# я немогу нормально вивести переменную shop, тоесть я пишу в консоле: shop а мне висвечивает типа токое: >>>(тут ничего не пишет) помогите ^-^

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
введите сюда код
print("начнем игру! =D")
#переменные >:E
#деньги $_$
money = 'деньги'
bmoney = 10
#усталость :(
sleep = 'спать'
fatigue = 100
#еда >:D
eat = 'кушать'
hungry = 100
food = 5
#места /\
work = 'работа'
shop = 'магазин'
home = 'Дом'
#взаимодействие с днем ) >>> *
nday = 'след день'
#код
print("money - заробатевать деньги, sleep - спать, eat - кушать, shop - пойти в магазин")
#вибрать взаимодействие >:|
actition = input("Выбрать взаимодействие: ")
#умови (выбрать взаимодействие (магазин))
if actition == shop:
    print("напишите \'home\' чтоб отпрввится домой!")
    print("Ви в магазині")
    print("купить кушать \'bfood\'")
    buy = input("Вибрать взаимодействие")
    if buy == home:
        print("Вы дома")
        actition = input("Выбрать взаимодействие: ")
    if buy == bfood:
        print("ви купили їжу \'їжа + 5, гроші - 5\'")
        money = bmoney - 5
        food = food + 5
```

---

вот что у меня виходит (ЕТО УЖЕ В КОНСОЛИ):

```
введите сюда код
================= RESTART: C:/Users/Service/Desktop/lifegame.py ================
начнем игру! =D
money - заробатевать деньги, sleep - спать, eat - кушать, shop - пойти в магазин
Выбрать взаимодействие: shop
>>> 
>>> shop
'магазин'
>>>
```

Comment: стоит взять учебник и ознакомиться с основами использования языка. Ну или нагуглить.

Comment: "заробатевать" - это интересно на каком языке?)

Comment: @Эникейщик, причём русского....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Выбрать взаимодействие: shop
> ```

А вводить надо `магазин`. И пользоваться отладчиком.